# Copy and paste the link from clipboard in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, return-value, return-type

I'm having the following issue:
I'm saving the locators as

```
public static By CopyUrl =  By.XPath("//a[@data-key='UrlLink']");
```

In the test, I cannot `GetText()`, or store the whole `CopyUrl` in a `var`, since it's `void`. `Driver.Click(XPath.MainMenu.Tabs.CopyUrl);`

How can I store the link which is saved in clipboard after I click on it, and paste it in a new tab.

I tried:

```
var elem =Driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab).Navigate().GoToUrl("myCopiedUrl").ToString();

Driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab).Navigate().GoToUrl(elem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [Test, Order(01234)]
    public void t_Document_CopyUrl_Downloaded()
    {
        NavigateToYourPage();
        UploadNewDocument();
        NavigateToTheSpecificTab();
        
        //Click on "Copy URL"
        string fileName = Driver.FindElement(XPath.Input).GetValue();
        IWebElement copyUrl = Driver.FindElement(XPath.CopyUrl);
        string currentUrl = copyUrl.GetAttribute("textContent");
        Driver.Click(XPath.CopyUrl);
        Driver.WaitForNoSpinner();

        // Opens a new tab and switches to new tab
        Driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(currentUrl);


        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads/");
        string downloadedFileName = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#name').textContent;");
        Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[0]);

        Assert.IsTrue(downloadedFileName.StartsWith(fileName));

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for you since both `Click()` and `Navigate().GoToUrl()` methods are returning void.
In order to get the current URL you should use this method:

```cs
String currentURL =  driver.Url;
```

or

```cs
String currentURL =  driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

or

```cs
String currentURL =  driver.getLocation();
```

Comment: At least if I could extract the value after the the click, so that I can play with it. 
The thing is that the whole project is using By and Xpath.

Comment: What value do you want to extract,  from where?

Comment: After I click the link where the  Url is copied, Driver.Click(XPath.MainMenu.Tabs.CopyUrl); 
I want to extract the url, which looks like this: 
https://localhost/myApp/document.ashx?id=a3deff91-3bd1-4ad5-a477-451ed971e264#

Comment: So, the problem is resolved now or you still need help?

Comment: The String currentURL = driver.Url; , somehow, it worked, but what it does -> it uses the current page URL and when I paste it as parameters, it only opens a new tab, with the URL I was on. 
After doing this, 
Driver.Click(XPath.MainMenu.Tabs.CopyUrl);
String curentUrl = Driver.Url;
Driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab).Navigate().GoToUrl(curentUrl);
I only had a new tab opened, and in the URL it was actually the URL which was on the first tab. 
For the other two methods, it didn`t work. 
The thing is, that also I`m not allowed to modify the Framework, or adding Nugets.

Comment: The error displayed for other two methods: 
'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: You probably need to switch the driver to the new tab after clicking on the element opening the new tab. Selenium don't know you want to go to the new tab automatically. Also getting the new url value should be done when the new url is already open.